# Can't change default nuxt favicon

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, nuxt.js, favicon

I am new to nuxt and trying to change default favicon in my project.

I changed the `favicon.png` and `favicon.ico` in my `static` folder. => **didn't work**.

changed the `favicon.png` and `favicon.ico` in my `dist` folder. => **didn't work**.

replaced the proper files generated by favicon generator websites in my `dist/_nuxt/icons` folder. => **didn't work**.

and this is my `nuxt.config.js`

```
head: {
    title: "my first nuxt proj - main page",
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: pkg.description }
    ],
    link: [{ rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.png' }],
  },
```

am I missing something?

Comment: Should be working the way you do it. Could you try to remove client cache?

Comment: @ajobi I found a bad trick. it is about size

Comment: Ahh okay, didn't expect that :D

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I found the solution, but it's kind of tricky and it's a little far from logic.

the size of the favicon should be **32*32** pixels or nuxt will load the default favicon itself.

and about my tries, it's enough to have a file in your `static` folder and give the path to `nuxt.config.js`.

but I'm still confused with the solution.

Comment: I did this and it worked for the base favicon, but the icon is still the default NUXT icon for other link tags (e.g rel="apple-touch-icon")

Comment: I found that there's a node_modules/.cache/pwa/icon directory.  I had to remove that and set   

`pwa: {
    source: '~/static/icon.png'
  },`
in nuxt.config.js

Comment: @tgf I think it should be `pwa: { icon: { source: '~/static/icon.png' } }` That is actually the source directory set [by default](https://pwa.nuxtjs.org/icon/#options)

Comment: There are uite a few websites doing that but you may use [this one](https://www.imgonline.com.ua/eng/resize-image.php) to generate a 32x32 sized icon.

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried replace `type: 'image/x-icon'` with `type: 'image/png'`?

The infos about this attribute and tag generally can be read [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_sizes.asp)

nuxt will convert object like `{ head: { link: [{ rel: 'icon', type: 'image/png', href: '/favicon.png' }] }}` to

```
<head>
  <link rel='icon' type='image/png' href='/favicon.png'>
</head>
```

So you can use any attributes listed in the article above.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a useful answer, in that it appears you are guessing at the solution, and don't provide context into how/why this solution might work. I think this would be better left as a comment to the OP

Comment: I couldn't leave a comment, sry. but anyway, You were trying to use png as favicon and facing sizing conflict. That's why it can be a solution. At least it works for me

Comment: I gotcha @Mik, I forgot about needing rep to comment. Can you update that additional info in your answer at your convenience? Just to make your answer the best it can be =) Looks like the OP may have solved by now, but your answer could be useful to another in the future

Comment: this answer is to sweep something under the carpet, not solve the question

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes it happens when pwa icon stucked in cache.
You just need to rename pwa icon in nuxt.config.js like this:

[image]

And may be after that it will needs to rebuild project.

Comment: It is possible that the image you linked might not be available at some point in the future. As such, it would be nice if you could put the code into your answer instead of linking an image.

Comment: Please, post relevant code as text, not an image. Unlike images, text can be easily copied and searched.

Comment: Make sure someone else didn't overwrite your `pwa` in the same file also... happened to me.

Comment: Solved the issue for me!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem running a SSR nuxt app. A couple of things to keep in mind:

1. You need to address the issue with your favicon.png (16x16 pixels or 32x32 pixels as @Hossein stated) and your icon.png file in the static directory. It appears `nuxt` generates icons based on the icon.png at `/static/icon.png` ([ref](https://pwa.nuxtjs.org/icon/)). That file should be at least 512x512 ([ref](https://pwa.nuxtjs.org/setup)). From my test, if it is too small, it has problems generating the larger icons that end up in the `node_modules/.cache/pwa/icon` location pointed out by @tgf in comments. After running `npm run dev` you should see a updated icon and see the same thing after running `npm run build`.
2. I use matching markup...i.e for favicon.png use `rel: 'icon', type: 'image/png', href: '/favicon.png'` and if ico use `rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico'`. A bit old but [WC3 has example and docs](https://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon) for png.

Answer (score 3):

When it comes to **Nuxt 3** all you need to do is change the favicon.ico in **public** folder with your own icon

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, this is how I solved it:

```
{ rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
```

replace '/favicon.ico' with your icon url. Pay attention to keep **href** with **type**, then run `npm run build` in terminal. Then you can run your porduct again.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, Problem is ***CACHE***

If you remove all files in following directories, and after that, build again, your replaced icons work correctly!

```
{rootDir}/node_modules/.cache/pwa/icon
```

or

```
{rootDir}/node_modules/.cache/nuxt/dist/client/icons
```

Now, use following commands:

```
npm run build

npm run generate
```

I was reading the documentation of *[Nuxt PWA](https://pwa.nuxtjs.org/)* and *[Icon Module Section](https://pwa.nuxtjs.org/icon/)*, when this idea came to my mind!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i have the same issue, i use this on my head title. the value of company logo is url png, but still show nuxt icon

```
{ rel: 'icon', href: `${storedata.company_logo}?v1` }
```

if i see html, the url is generated

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it by converting my image to a favicon standard and format then using it and it was fixed.

but the main change you should make is in `nuxt.config.js` but with `favicon.ico`:

```
    head: {
    title: "my first nuxt proj - main page",
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: pkg.description }
        ],
        link: [{ rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }],
    },
```